# Pass array items return by function to another function as separate arguments

Tags: powershell-core

I want to pass the items of an array returned by a function to another function as separate arguments:

```
function f1 {
    return 1, 2, 3
}

function f2 {
    Write-Output $args.Length
}
```

Calling `f2 (f1)` writes 1, I need to use `@` with an intermediate variable

```
$r = f1
f2 @r
```

Is there a way to directly pass the return value of `f1` as separate arguments to `f2`?

Comment: I'm unsure if I really got what you mean but have you considered using a pipeline function?

Comment: @Olaf I don't really know what pipeline functions can do but I don't want to process each argument separately in `f2`. Typically `f2` would at some point forward the arguments somewhere else (as is).

Comment: Looks like a scope issue which is why declaring the variable outside of f1 and passing that to f2 works. Suggest calling f1 from within f2. Try replacing `write-output $args.length` with `(f1).length` and then just calling f2 with no arguments. Obviously, you could also assign the return value of f1 to a variable within f2.

Comment: @nimizen I don't want to call `f1` inside `f2`, `f1` and `f2` could be any functions, this is just an example.